# In SC 9.3 Marketing Automation Plan, will contacts go to the yes path immediately or wait until the time has elapsed?

Tags: marketing-automation

In Sitecore 9.3 Marketing Automation plan, I have the following Custom listener.  In this case, will the contact go to the yes path and continue as soon as it triggers the campaign and channel or will it have to wait until the 6 days elapse?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Sitecore marketing automation custom listener element, if a contact satisfies the rules or conditions, it will immediately move to the *Yes* path without waiting for the time mentioned in the *Listen For* field. But if conditions are not satisfied at that point of time, contact will wait and listen till the mentioned time and then after that time has elapsed, if conditions still not satisfied then contact will go to *No* path otherwise to the *Yes* path.

**Now in your case**: If the enrolled contact has not sent any email campaign or not interacted with any channel at the point of time when contact engages with the custom listener, then it will wait for 6 days otherwise it will go to the *Yes* path immediately.

Answer (score 0):

It will trigger the Yes path as soon as the contact triggers the Campaign.

The Marketing Automation will run(keep listening) for next 6 days as shown in the screen shot for all the contacts. Now if any of the contact triggers the Campaign then it will execute the Yes path